# Changing checkout data for next order subscription woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have 3 custom fields that I created in the Woocommerce store checkout for a particular subscription product. I was trying to create a form (on the account page) that users can use to change these 3 fields for the next order. For example:

1. Customer buys the subscription and filled these 3 fields in the checkout
2. The customer wants to change these 3 fields for next month's order, goes into the account, and fills out the form (with 3 fields)
3. Next month's order automatically generated by Wooommerce will include these 3 updated fields in the order details.

Is this something possible that can be made?

I tried to make a form in the php account (subscription) template however I am not sure if there is a way to change this data for the next order that still needs to be create by the system.

Comment: Yes, it's totally possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.